# In tkinter-python statement INSERT to SQLite with field Double data type ,can't convert float to string implicitly

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

In Tkinter , Python 3.4
SQLite3 : DB.cuota REAL

Tkinter Statement :

```
cur.execute ( "INSERT INTO lista_clientes ( cuota, nit, nombre ) VALUES(" + lcuota.get() + "," + \
               + "'" + lnit.get() + "'" + ","  + "'" + lnombre.get() + "'" + ")" );
conn.commit()

lcuota = DoubleVar()
```

> TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

What error cause  `lcuota.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

`lcuota.get()` is returning float value, which you have to type caste into string type using `str(lcuota.get())`, before concatenating it with string.

Try this :

```
cur.execute ( "INSERT INTO lista_clientes ( cuota, nit, nombre ) VALUES(" + str(lcuota.get()) + "," \
               + "'" + str(lnit.get()) + "'" + ","  + "'" + str(lnombre.get()) + "'" + ")" );
```

Comment: this statement result in : bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: Thanks for your answer